# Using .NET Reflector to see how naming rules are implemented in Resharper

Tags: resharper, reflector

The following is a default rule with standard Resharper (without plugins) indicating a naming rule violation.

[image: one of the naming rules in Resharper]
I would like to understand how custom naming rules are implemented in Resharper using Open API. So would like to deassemble (using Reflector) the corresponding dll file in which this rule is implemented.

Can you pls guide me which dll file(s) I need to check/deassemble for checking how this naming rule is implemented.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the ReShaper.Daemon.Specific.dll.
Find there "CheckNamespace" class